# .htaccess script has redirection to duplicate url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect to https:// and without www. Found some .htaccess scripts that would work, and they work except for when I try to reach the site by using http://www.example.com When using this url I get redirected to https://www.example.com/https:/www.example.com which is weird in my opinion.

I've tried to find other scripts to see if they would work but have not found anything yet.

Forgot to add the script I'm currently using...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://5timesrock.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, then we can see if we can help with that.

Comment: So `5timesrock.nl` is the actual domain name in question? Accessing `http://www.5timesrock.nl` in my browser, I get redirected to `https://5timesrock.nl`- so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: In my browser when I visit http://www.5timesrock.nl I get redirected to https://5timesrock.nl/https:/www.5timesrock.nl

Comment: Your browser probably still has an old, faulty redirect cached. Try in a private window.

Comment: Yes thanks! Didn't know your browser could have faulty redirect cache... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As CBroe commented, using a private browser fixed my issue. It was due to old, faulty redirect cache!